# Как записать звук с микрофона и колонок в один поток?

Tags: c++, winapi, аудио, directshow

Я написал фильтр DirectShow для захвата звука, который проигрывается в системе.
Написан с использованием WASAPI Loopback.
Мне нужно записать этот звук и звук с микрофона в один поток.

Как сделать сведение двух потоков в DirectShow?